# Unidentified symbol

Tags: java, io, symbols

Given the following:

```
import java.io.*;

public class WriteRead {

    public void writeToFile(String filename) throws IOException {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filename);
        fw.write("testing");
        fw.close();
    }

    public String readFromFile(String filename) throws IOException {
    String str = "";
    int characterInt = 0;
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(filename);
        while (characterInt != -1) {
            characterInt = fr.read();
            str += "" + (char) characterInt;
        }
    fr.close();
    return str;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    WriteRead wR = new WriteRead();
    wR.writeToFile("test.java");
    System.out.println(wR.readFromFile("test.java"));
  }
}
```

when I run the program it prints the following:

[image]

What is the symbol at the end of "testing" and what part of the program causes it to be there?

Comment: Open your file with a hex editor and post the hexcode of this character

Comment: Everthing looks fine...... no idea.... sry...

Comment: Least of your worries and nothing to do with the question, I know, but the read and write methods are named in kind of an inconsistent way, and one is static while the other is not, and this makes my inner reviewer squirm and writhe. #nitpick

Comment: while (characterInt != -1) allows your program to jump one extra space after the end of the document so it is printing the end of file character

Comment: Something off topic, your `getContent()` is a typical candidate to use `StringBuilder`/`StringBuffer` instead of string concat.

Comment: Thanks all. Tot Zam - that's solved it! hiergiltdiestfu - apologies, I took the code from a bigger program. I've now edited the code so that it's more consistent. Adrian Shum - I didn't know about StringBuilder / StringBuffer and it'll be useful to make use of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the changes as below:

```
while ((characterInt = fr.read()) != -1) {
            //characterInt = fr.read();
            str += "" + (char) characterInt;
        }
```

Read the `char` and compare it with `-1 as EOF`. You were appending the `end of file char` in string and then while loop condition was getting failed.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code-

```
while ((characterInt = fr.read()) != -1) {
            str += "" + (char) characterInt;
        }
```

since in last iteration when this reads `-1` this appends `?` in `str` so please check before adding.and as far as your display of `testing0` is concern give me hexcode of this first.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting `characterInt = fr.read();` inside your `while`loop. You should set this either outside `while`loop or in `while()`condition.

So as per your code, it will run for second iteration also because in second iteration, your `characterInt` is not equal to `-1` (it is holding earlier value i.e. testing).